# Play framework 2.3.x OAuth & Actors "Cannot find HTTP Request Header here"

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, twitter-oauth

I'm using the example code from Play's [ScalaOAuth documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaOAuth) to authenticate to the twitter API. My full code is here:

```
object Twitter extends Controller {

  val KEY = ConsumerKey("redacted")

val TWITTER = OAuth(ServiceInfo(
"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize", KEY),
true)

def authenticate = Action { request =>
request.getQueryString("oauth_verifier").map { verifier =>
  val tokenPair = sessionTokenPair(request).get
  // We got the verifier; now get the access token, store it and back to index
  TWITTER.retrieveAccessToken(tokenPair, verifier) match {
    case Right(t) => {
      // We received the authorized tokens in the OAuth object - store it before we proceed
      Redirect(routes.Application.timeline).withSession("token" -> t.token, "secret" -> t.secret)
    }
    case Left(e) => throw e
  }
}.getOrElse(
    TWITTER.retrieveRequestToken("http://localhost:9000/auth") match {
      case Right(t) => {
        // We received the unauthorized tokens in the OAuth object - store it before we proceed
        Redirect(TWITTER.redirectUrl(t.token)).withSession("token" -> t.token, "secret" -> t.secret)
      }
      case Left(e) => throw e
    })
}

def sessionTokenPair(implicit request: RequestHeader): Option[RequestToken] = {
for {
  token <- request.session.get("token")
  secret <- request.session.get("secret")
} yield {
  RequestToken(token, secret)
}
}

}
```

I spin up an actor that I want to use to search the Twitter API. I also use an edited version of their controller in that documentation to do this:

```
 class TwitterParse extends Actor {

private var buildURL: String = _
private val urlBoilerPlate = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q="
private val pageCount = "&page=1&count=3"

 def receive = {
case rawName: (Long, String) => { 

  buildURL = urlBoilerPlate + rawName._2 + pageCount

  Twitter.sessionTokenPair match {
    case Some(credentials) => {
      WS.url(buildURL)
        .sign(OAuthCalculator(Twitter.KEY, credentials))
        .get
        .map(result => println(result.json))
    }

  }

}
```

When I compile I get: **"Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here"** on the Twitter.sessionTokenPair call. This probably has to do with the fact that in their docs they include a

```
Action.async { implicit request =>
```

before calling sessionTokenPair. How would I fix this so it works in the Actor?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Think about the problem. Your actor just needs some initial state, in this case the Twitter client API token and secret, which in the code example these come from the request session. Perhaps put them in the actor `Props`?

Comment: Mikesname, I understand conceptually what you're advising, but could you go into a bit more detail? I'm assuming we change this somehow:           case Right(t) => {
          // We received the authorized tokens in the OAuth object - store it before we proceed
          Redirect(routes.Application.timeline).withSession("token" -> t.token, "secret" -> t.secret)
        }                                                                                                             to pass it to twitterParse's constructor?

Comment: I solved this by hardcoding the ConsumerKey and RequestToken into my actor (both obtained from twitter API profile) and passing those to twitter with WS.sign